# Can I trigger an action in python from a wagtail page button

Tags: python, wagtail

In wagtail, it's possible to add a button to a page, using the [`register_page_listing_buttons`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/reference/hooks.html?highlight=hooks#register-page-listing-buttons) hook.

However, those examples simply take you to a url of your choosing.

In my case, I have a `ProjectPage` model, and I have a function `regenerate_project_geo_features()` (presently a management command, although it doesn't need to be).

I want a button, either in the page listing or in the page edit view itself, which can be used to trigger an action in python.

**Is it possible to adapt that hook, or use another that I'm not aware of, to simply call a function in python? (preferably with some parameter like a `ProjectPage` `id` to tell the function what page it was called on)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this would be with Javascript, essentially adding a listener to the link/button being clicked. This would then trigger a POST request of some kind to a URL you manage which would do the 'work' of the regeneration.

Essentially as this is a web framework (Django), everything should be considered as a bunch of views (pages) with request/response handling.

### Approach

- Create a custom admin URL & view (intentionally accessible via admin only)
- This view would basically handle `POST` requests and when called with the id of the page, it will do the work you require.
- The link now becomes a button in purpose only, clicking it will call with Javascript [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (happens in the background)
- You can then  update your view to do whatever you want to the page in the background.
- Note: example is rough and does not have any error handling or messaging to the user (ie. when they click it, they do not know if it has worked/completed etc).

### Example Code

- This would be in your `wagtail_hooks.py` file

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from wagtail.admin.widgets import PageListingButton
from wagtail.core import hooks


@csrf_exempt # not recommended - but helpful to get to the POC stage
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def regnerate_admin_features(request):
    page_pk = request.GET.get('id', '')
    # do whatever you need here with the PK to process the action

    return HttpResponse(
        "Success/Error handling goes here",
        content_type="text/plain")

@hooks.register('register_admin_urls')
def urlconf_time():
  return [
    url(r'^regenerate_geo_features/$', regnerate_admin_features, name='regenerate_geo_features'),
  ]

@hooks.register('register_page_listing_buttons')
def page_listing_buttons(page, page_perms, is_parent=False):

    attrs = {
        'data-id': page.pk, # note - may want to html encode this for a more secure implementation
    }

    yield PageListingButton(
        'Regenerate Geo Features',
        reverse('regenerate_geo_features'),
        attrs=attrs,
        classes=["action-regenerate-geo-features"],
        priority=100
    )

@hooks.register('insert_global_admin_js')
def global_admin_js():
    # note - this is very rough, no error, loading or sucess messaging
    # reminder - using format_html means all `{` must be written as `{{`
    return format_html(
        """
        <script>
        const onClickHandler = function(event) {{
            event.preventDefault(); // ensure the hash does not change
            const url = event.target.href + '?id=' + event.target.dataset.id;
            console.log('button clicked - about to POST to URL:', url);
            fetch(url, {{
                method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
            }})
        }};

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {{
            const actionButtons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('action-regenerate-geo-features'));

            actionButtons.forEach(function(element) {{
                element.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
            }});
        }});
        </script>
        """,
    )
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks @LB! What a thorough and well crafted answer. Thank you so much for your time spent here!!!